# Where can I buy stickers/labels to put on rack systems/servers to identify them?

Tags: datacenter, rack, labeler

Where can I buy stickers/labels to put on rack systems/servers to identify them?    I want to put my companies logo on them and also I want 2 sizes:  small and larger.  The larger stickers should have a place to write the IP Address on them and/or the system name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sysadmins typically use [P-Touch labelers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0047T7JMW) to identify servers by name and IP address. It is best to use a PC-connectable model with an ample supply of [white-on-black TZ tape](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004I2I05S). Note that the "default" label tape color is black-on-white, which is more likely to look unattractive or unprofessional on a black server chassis.

As for stickers with your company logo, you may want to look at getting asset tags which include not only your company name or logo but also a serial number. Both accounting people  and security auditors generally smile upon the use of asset tags ([example](http://www.mavericklabel.com/products/asset_designer.php?48[]=AT011NO&12[]=384)), especially when the tag numbers have been entered into an asset-tracking database like [OCS Inventory NG](http://www.ocsinventory-ng.org/).

Comment: White-on-Black versus Black-on-White is a personal choice -- I favor Black-on-White myself because it makes the sticker stand out when you're scanning the rack looking for a specific host (sadly many of my systems are older and only have an ID light on the front.  Typically I'm in the back of the rack when I need to get at a box), but as long as you're consistent...

Comment: Also +1 for asset tags (the kind that don't want to come off, and leave a checkerboard mark behind if you tear 'em off).  Auditors and accountants LOVE these things, and if your servers aren't physically secure there is a slim chance they may actually be useful one day in deterring theft.

Comment: Certainly! As far as the *back* of the server goes, I'd actually agree with you that white-on-black would be preferable. It can be dark in there! However, I would venture that in most contemporary environments, we hope not to look at the backsides of servers very often once they are installed and commissioned...

Comment: That's true, but all it takes is one unfortunate unplugging of the wrong machine (say the one that's still alive after a HA pair suffers a hardware failure) -- (other people's) bitter experience has taught me the virtue of labeling both sides of a box :)

Answer (score 2):

Talk to any company that sells stickers or labels. Google is your friend.

You'll find that most shops use some variant of a [dymo](http://global.dymo.com/) label maker, and dispense with the logo bit.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just pick up some of [these](http://www.averylabelsonline.com/avrela.html) and design and print them yourself.

That said, I've never seen a company that had their logo printed on the server/rack labels - often there's very little space available on the front panel of most servers, making it difficult to apply anything but a small label with hostname.

Additionally - you *really* don't want to hand-write these labels - that's just asking for problems. As voretaq7 suggested, pick up a label printer and be done with it.

Comment: Honestly I don't even bother with the IP.  Short-Qualified hostname (`app01`, `app02`, `db01`, `db02`, etc.) stuck on the CD-ROM tray and on one of the PCI slot blanks in the back is as far as I'll usually go.

Comment: Agreed. I've actually not even been ordering optical drives on my servers lately (HP DL 380 series), which has made it challenging to find a spot to stick a label without covering up air intake holes.

Comment: That's about the only reason I still get the optical drives (and that I haven't had time to set up a proper netboot-installation environment, so we still do a CD install to populate the bare metal)

Comment: I still do CD-install, but via the iLO remote media option instead of a physical drive.

Comment: I had to label a SuperMicro chassis the other day where the entire front of the chassis was covered in 24x drive bays. In the end I just had to wrap the label around the rack handles.

Comment: @ErikA Indeed, optical drives in 2011 are looking a lot like floppy drives in 1998. Save for Apple, the entire industry remains *quite sure* that they are needed on every device, despite that they are undoubtedly vestigial (and often detrimental) in almost every enterprise context.